# Configure a Netty application to use a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, netty

Telerik has an how-to on [Configure a Java Application to Use Fiddler](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp). That does not seem to work (meaning it seems to have no effect) with our Netty based application, which I assume is because that would only apply to applications that use the default J2SE built-in HTTP libraries? Also see [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) in the Java SE docs.

Is there a standard way of configuring a Netty based application for picking up proxying, or would I need to manually add a handler to the channel pipeline that would change the HTTP requests (and responses?) to use the proxy? If the latter, is there a standard handler I could employ that has all the logic for setting headers, changing urls, etc. built-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [proxy package in Netty](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/proxy/package-summary.html), in which [HttpProxyHandler](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/proxy/HttpProxyHandler.html) seems to be what you are looking for, with regards to the last question on whether there is standard handler built-in. Have not used it, though, so cannot say whether or not it picks up on those system props.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/887